# CSV file with Italic values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, csv

Is there any way to create a csv file using c#, which can have/show few values in Italic format, when we open it in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just not possible. Theres no markup in csv. Either export an xls(x) or rethink your problem/solution. Why csv? It's not really meant for people to read. Only to transfer data from one application to another.

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file is a text file where Excel can only interpret the type of field content as best (text, numeric, date) but not within a field. So the short answer is no.

There are libraries available for the ASP.NET MVC environment which allow you to create true Excel files so you then have complete control over field formats etc. A quick Google will find these.

**UPDATE**

A possible solution, if you are using MVC, is to create an HTML 'file' and then download that:

```
this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Employees.xls");
this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
return this.Content(sb.ToString());
```

I've never tried this but have seen that it *might* work.

Comment: i know csv is a text file, actually i am hoping that if i can add some tag with values and excel can read it and format the cell..

Comment: the thing is that, i want to give option of export to CSV only, but if that file is opened in excel then that should show some cells as italic...

Comment: I'm afraid I know of no way of doing that.